# Deny creating table by Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created ViewModel and Entity Framework force me to create table (and key property) to the database. But I do not need that. How to deny it?

In controler:

```
    public ActionResult Detail(int Id)
    {
        var team = _context.Teams.Single(t => t.Id == Id);

        if (team == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var teamDetail = new TeamDetail
        {
            Team = team,
            fighters = _context.Users
                .Where(u => u.TeamId == team.Id && u.TeamConfirmed)
                .ToList()
        };

        return View(teamDetail);
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class TeamDetail
{
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public List<ApplicationUser> fighters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework is forcing you? What??

Comment: It want to make a table (with add-migration)

TournamentApp2.Models.TeamDetail: : EntityType 'TeamDetail' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
TeamDetails: EntityType: EntitySet 'TeamDetails' is based on type 'TeamDetail' that has no keys defined.

Comment: We need to see your dbcontext.

Comment: Have you used the `TeamDetail` class somewhere in the entity models - for instance in `Team` class?

Comment: thank you Ivan. EF inserted `public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TournamentApp2.ViewModels.TeamDetail> TeamDetails { get; set; }` to the end of ApplicationDbContext. Any idea why it happen? Actually it happen to me for the second time. First time when I was adding nullable foreign key to some class.